# What is the Objective C attribute (@property) assignment message passing notation?

Tags: objective-c

What is the Objective C attribute (@property) assignment message passing notation?

name is a property declared in another file, retain, synthesize ... everything in order.

In main.m i have this one line

calculator.name=@"Martin";

What is the message passing equivalent of this? How do i set an attribute via message passing, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[calculator setName: @"Martin"];
```

http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103

Comment: From your website NSLog(@"%d", test0.iVar); How would "test0.iVar" (getting a value of an attribute) look via message passing?

Comment: It's not my website:). And the answer is [test0 iVar]